# Issue with django rendering data onto template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

I'm trying to render info on the html file, but info doesn't seem to be coming through correctly.

In the html below, it is supposed to render items that correspond with it's menu title.

For example

> Title : Desserts
>
> Item: Ice-cream
>
> Description: Nice chocolate ice cream with sprinkles
>
> $: 3.00
>
> ---
>
> Title : Mains
>
> Item: Curry
>
> Description: Curry is hot
>
> $: 10.00

The issue I'm facing is that all item in menuitems appears under all menu titles. The titles renders okay.

For example

> Title : Desserts
>
> Item: Ice-cream
>
> Description: Nice chocolate ice cream with sprinkles
>
> $: 3.00

---

> Title : Mains
>
> Item: Ice-cream
>
> Description: Nice chocolate ice cream with sprinkles
>
> $: 3.00

html

```
    {% for menu in menus %}
    <section id="services">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-heading">Title {{ menu.title }}</h2>
                <hr class="primary">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                {% for item in menuitems %}
                    <p>Item {{ item.item_name }}</p>
                    <p>Description {{ item.description }}</p>
                    <p>$ {{ item.price }}</p>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>    

    {% endfor %}
```

**How do I make sure the info shows up under the correct titles?**

views.py

```
def single(request, slug):
    user = request.user
    restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(slug=slug)
    template = 'restaurants/single.html'
    menus = restaurant.menutitle_set.all()

    menuitems = MenuItem.objects.filter(title=menus)



    context = {
            'restaurant': restaurant,
            'menus': menus,
            'menuitems': menuitems,
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

models.py

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    restaurant_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    restaurant_address1 = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    restaurant_address2 = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    restaurant_state = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=STATE_CHOICES)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.restaurant_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("single_restaurant", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})


class MenuTitle(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class MenuItem(models.Model):
    title = models.ForeignKey(MenuTitle)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    description = MarkdownField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.item_name
```

admin.py

```
class MenuTitleInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = MenuTitle
    extra = 1

class MenuItemInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = MenuItem
    extra = 1

class RestaurantAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("restaurant_name",)}

    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant

    inlines = [MenuTitleInline]

admin.site.register(Restaurant, RestaurantAdmin)


class MenuTitleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["restaurant", "title"]
    class Meta:
        model = MenuTitle
    inlines = [MenuItemInline]

admin.site.register(MenuTitle, MenuTitleAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove `menuitems` from view (or just don't add `menuitems` to context) and replace `{% for item in menuitems %}` with `{% for item in menu.menuitem_set.all %}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
{% for item in menuitems %}
     <p>Item {{ item.item_name }}</p>
     <p>Description {{ item.description }}</p>
     <p>$ {{ item.price }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Change this code to ,

```
{% for item in menu.menuitem.all %}
   <p>Item {{ item.item_name }}</p>
   <p>Description {{ item.description }}</p>
   <p>$ {{ item.price }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Geo Jacob has suggested, made those changes. Also in the view function, no need to set "menuitems" variable in the context dictionary.